# Bash and Functions

Tags: bash

I am to write a basg=h script that displays a message if you input the correct number (i.e. 1 = function f1, 2 = function f2, and 3 = function f3)

My code is as follow

```
 #!/bin/bash

function f1
{
     echo "This message is from function 1"
}

function f2
{
    echo "This messge is from function 2"
}

function f3
{
    echo "This message is from function 3"
}

function=$(typeset -F)

declare -a myarr=(`echo "$function" [sed 's/declare[ ]-f / /g'`)

read -p "Enter a number (1, 2, or 3): " number

if ! [[ "$number" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
    then
        echo "Not a valid number"
        exit
fi

flag=0

for element in "${myarr[@]}
do

    if echo "$element" | grep -q "$num"; then
        $element

        flag=1
    fi
done

if [ "$flag" -eq 0 ]; then
echo "No function matches number $num"
fi
```

Now when I run the code I obtain the error

> q6: line 43: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
>
> q6: line 45: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Any help sourcing the errors?

Comment: ssh isn't used by the code in the question anywhere. Why is it tagged?

Comment: More generally (and seriously), though -- a good StackOverflow question revolves around *one single* error, where you already looked for duplicates in the knowledgebase, isolated the shortest code that produces that error, etc. Posting code with a bunch of unrelated errors means you still have work to do before you've got something ready to ask. See the [mcve] definition for guidance on coming up with a good code sample for asking about such a single, isolated error.

Comment: (...and as an aside, if you look at how `declare -f` outputs a function, with no `function` keyword, that's an important hint: The syntax it uses is the POSIX-compliant function definition syntax, and it's the one you should be using too; see discussion in http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete)

Answer (score 1):

```
for element in "${myarr[@]}
```

Missing the end quote. You can catch errors like this by seeing where the syntax highlighting goes wonky. Notice how much of the script following this line is incorrectly colored red?

Even better, you can use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/):

```
Line 32:
for element in "${myarr[@]}
^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this for loop.
               ^-- SC1078: Did you forget to close this double quoted string?
```

Fix that and you get:

```
Line 1:
 #!/bin/bash
^-- SC1114: Remove leading spaces before the shebang.

Line 20:
declare -a myarr=(`echo "$function" [sed 's/declare[ ]-f / /g'`)
                  ^-- SC2207: Prefer mapfile or read -a to split command output (or quote to avoid splitting).
                  ^-- SC2006: Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
                  ^-- SC2116: Useless echo? Instead of 'cmd $(echo foo)', just use 'cmd foo'.

Line 22:
read -p "Enter a number (1, 2, or 3): " number
^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.

Line 35:
    if echo "$element" | grep -q "$num"; then
                                  ^-- SC2154: num is referenced but not assigned.
```

Comment: thank you, my errors do not show as I use SSH terminal! At least on mine it does not!